# Android: Getting Error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed

Tags: android

I am building an app on android and running into an error and while searching on net, came across your posting on this and changed the eclipse.ini to increase Xms and Xmx params but still this error does not go away.

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java with Android SDK 2.1 on Mac OS. Please help or please point me to someone who might know.

Btw, this error only happens when i add external jar files (which i need for my project). Here are the list of external jar files that i have in my classpath.)

- httpclient-4.0.1.jar from apache
- httpcore -4.0.1.jarfrom apache
- commons-codec-1.3.jar from apache
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar from apache
- json_simple-1.1.jar from google

Here is the complete error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/AvalonLogger;
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:143)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:301)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:278)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$100(Main.java:56)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:229)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.cf <http://com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.pro> .direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:130)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:108)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:247)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:183)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:139)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.DexWrapper.run(Unknown Source)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.ApkBuilder.executeDx(Unknown Source)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.ApkBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:627)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:170)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:201)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:253)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:309)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:341)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:140)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:238)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp] 4 errors; aborting
[2010-05-02 21:57:05 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Comment: Was there a solution to this? I see it in intellij also.

Comment: What's solution on intellij idea? ADT is ok

Answer (score 21):

In r14 they changed the way in which external libraries are referenced and it can cause this problem. You can fix it by removing the linked folders (with _src in the name) from the folder tree:

- Right click and select "Build Path > Remove from build path"
- A popup will open. Make sure that “Also unlink the folder from the project” is checked and then accept it.

see http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html

Comment: This was the ONLY solution that fixed my problem. Thanks for posting this

Comment: I removed the jar from the build path. Now the project does not run at all.

Answer (score 6):

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   already added:
>   Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/AvalonLogger;

You are attempting to add `org.apache.commons.logging.impl.AvalonLogger` twice to your project. Do not do that.

Also, much of what you are adding via JARs is already in Android, such as HttpClient. This may be contributing to your error.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this as well but I made sure ahead of time that I did not have a duplicate class in my jar file.  This was some other issue dealing with multiple loading of the same jar or something.  The classpath and the list of Referenced Libraries looked appropriate.  After some flailing around, some combination of the following fixed it:

- I was using a different external jar that was also local in the directory.  I removed it from the build-path and re-added it from the local jar instead.
- I removed all external jars and re-added them one at a time making sure they were the right ones.
- I removed the .classpath file in my project as well as the bin and gen directories.
- I cleaned the project in Eclipse, forcing the files to be regenerated.
- I also shuffled around the jar file above the gen directory in the build order.

Some combination of the above seemed to fix the issue.  If it happens again, I will be more careful to see if I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

I had written a blog post about one possible cause of this error and its solution [here](http://omer-muhammed.blogspot.com/2010/03/android-error-conversion-to-dalvik.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the long description on your blog, too bad this didn't help me ;(

Answer (score 2):

i guess that you put your jar in folder for example library and then, build path from this folder. You just remove this jar file and try select **property** from project, then **Java build path** -> **Add external jars** files. It will works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I put the .jar under my `src/` directory, so Eclipse copied it to the `bin/` directory and tried to link it from both places. Moving it from `src/` to `libs/` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was due to having the same project references also in library projects. A few updates ago this was normal behaviour, but since the change in library handling, I now needed to remove the references from my projects and have only one of the libraries reference it.

Answer (score 1):

This always happened to me after I did a custom build using a custom command using proguard.

I solved this problem by emptying the bin directory of my eclipse project directory and then cleaning the project (Eclipse menu "project" --> "clean...")

Obviously proguard makes a mess in this directory by which Eclipse gets confused...

Answer (score 0):

I get really mad with this problem trying to do all the posible solutions, but none worked for me: Clean project, Re-build, erasing libraries, linking again the libraries, updating proguard, editing proguard files...

Finally the solution was much more easy: **Project**, **Android Tools**, **Fix project propieties**.

Now I can export the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the src and gen folders and select Build Path > Remove from Build Path.
then
Right Click > Build Path > Use as Source Folder

Answer (score 0):

i got that from time to time when i tried to run code in an incompatible version of android (ie 2.2 when 4.0 was needed for a particular library to work)