# Facebook android sdk v4 login cancel

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

i need implement facebook login in my app.Here is my class :

Manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
```

And my class :

```
public abstract class FaceBookActivityImpl extends BaseActivity {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private ShareDialog shareDialog;

@Override
protected void initView() {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);
}

public CallbackManager getCalbackManager(){
    return callbackManager;
}

public ShareDialog getShareDialog(){
    if(shareDialog==null){
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        // this part is optional
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                DebugLog.d("share success " + result.getPostId());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            }
        });
    }
    return shareDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

When user login , i need check publish_actions for like action:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(((MainActivity) getContext()).getCalbackManager(), new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        DebugLog.d("login fb success "+loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
                        likeTopic();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        DebugLog.d("login fb cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        DebugLog.d("login fb error "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(((MainActivity) getContext()), Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

But , it's alway cancel :

```
DebugLog.d("login fb cancel");
```

What i'm missing , please help me , i've research for long time .
Thanks you so much.

**Edit :**
when it happened , the logcat(with no filter ) show:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.login.LoginClient$Request" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
```

Comment: do you have some results?

Comment: There's a bug for Facebook for this issue, (currently closed due to inactivity), comment and subscribe for them to reopen it and solve it. developers.facebook.com/bugs/1621984714705591

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue arises if device have a native Facebook app installed. Try running code on a device which doesn't have Facebook app installed.

**Also**, try removing the app from Facebook developer's page and add it again.

See similar questions here

[Can't login to Facebook if Facebook app is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847130/cant-login-to-facebook-if-facebook-app-is-installed)

[Android Class not found : Didn't find class ... on path: DexPathList : link of class failed :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824273/android-class-not-found-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist-link-of-)**

**Update - Important**

You need to add **App Id** at the end of `FacebookContentProvider`, like `FacebookContentProvider1234`, if 1234 is your App Id. For Example

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: If i uninstall facebook app from my device ,it's ok .but user wont do it , do you think it is facebook sdk error?

Comment: I don't think so, it is a error on Facebook side,. I integrated FB sdk with my app and I tested it with and without native app, it was working fine

Comment: i think i need review for login,however, in this case , fb sdk should return clear error

Answer (score 0):

I you want to avoid call of Facebook app use this to set Facebook login behavior to use auth dialog only:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior( LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO );
```

or, if you uses LoginButton object for login:

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior( LoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue using facebook sdk 4.6.0 when I disable my installed facebook app. It needed some time to figure out that everything works fine without installed facebook app or installed facebook app enabled.

Due to it's a very special case that the facebbook app is installed and disabled, and because I also provide a google login. I don't investigate more time in this issue.

Happy Day